# WebLogic - Deploy SpringBoot war in WebLogic Server

Tags: java, spring, maven, deployment, weblogic

I am trying to convert a simple SpringBoot application to deploy in WebLogic. It works well in buildin TomCat server. Then I make changes to it and create a new war file. When I try to deploy the war file, I get this error.

WebLogic Console Error
[image: WebLogic Console Error]

**Servlet initializer for web.xml**

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SampleStsApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Application.java file

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements
        WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.simplain.samplests</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SampleSTS</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<properties>
        <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
<!--            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>demo.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

weblogic.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>demo</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>  <> <> <144201069                                                   8389>

```
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:161)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:327)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:817)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:415)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:779)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:792)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentLoader.getWebFragmentBean(WebFragmentLoader.java:36)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentManager.prepareForTopologicalSort(WebFragmentManager.java:164)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentManager.sortRelatively(WebFragmentManager.java:152)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentManager.sortFragments(WebFragmentManager.java:109)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentManager.<init>(WebFragmentManager.java:54)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentManager.<init>(WebFragmentManager.java:43)
    at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.initWebFragmentManager(WARModule.java:524)
    at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.merge(WARModule.java:549)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.ToolsModuleWrapper.merge(ToolsModuleWrapper.java:96)
    at weblogic.application.utils.CustomModuleManager.merge(CustomModuleManager.java:78)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleMergeFlow.proecessModule(SingleModuleMergeFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleFlow.compile(SingleModuleFlow.java:63)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.BaseMerger.merge(BaseMerger.java:20)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:75)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:40)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:144)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:156)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:94)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:58)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:182)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createLazyDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:157)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.inspect(SessionHelper.java:698)
    at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow$2.execute(Flow.java:476)
    at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5157)
    at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow.appSelected(Flow.java:474)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:87)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.java:264)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:262)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:134)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1129)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.internal.PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.strutsLookupInternal(PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.java:43)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:108)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:707)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:141)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:108)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:159)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:465)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:219)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:275)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to load java type corresponding to e=web-fragment@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.getPojoBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:371)
        at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:326)
        at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:336)
        at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineRootType(UnmarshalResult.java:317)
        at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshalResult.java:168)
        at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:67)
        at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:150)
        ... 133 more

Comment: can you also add your **web.xml**?

Comment: I dont have web.xml. I setup it in java code. I have added the java code also here.

Comment: but **web.xml* is required for *war* modules.

Comment: For Spring Boot project, it is not mandatory. We can do that using the java file. But I will also try to add web.xml and see how it behaves. Thanks

Comment: I also get the same error. Did you fix it ?

Comment: Hi Jay, after changing the datasource to a new version related to the latest code it work. So I am suspecting that the code access the table/data caused an issue.

Comment: @JosephSelvaraj Sorry mate I still have the same problem... can you please compare my git hub simple code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083997/not-able-to-deploy-a-simple-spring-boot-application-on-weblogic-12c

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic says you need to make your `@SpringBootApplication` class implement `WebApplicationInitializer` directly. Seems like WebLogic's logic uses reflection (wrongly) instead of doing an `instanceof` check.

The same page also cautions that you need to `wls:prefer-application-packages` for `org.slf4j` if you use logback (I don't know why, maybe jar incompatibilities).

Answer (score 0):

After confirming that I am implementing `WebApplicationInitializer` and the `wls:prefer-application-packages` as per @Toolforger's answer I found that adding the following dependency solved this for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This makes sure that the embedded tomcat server does not interfere with the WebLogic servlet, as per this article: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html