# unable to deploy spring boot built ear file on weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Am getting the below exception when I try to deploy a spring boot built EAR in weblogic .

pom file :

```
<groupId>com.xyz.someComp</groupId>
<artifactId>someAPI</artifactId>
<version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>My Rest API </name>
<description>My API for testing </description>




<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.database-rider</groupId>
        <artifactId>rider-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.database-rider</groupId>
        <artifactId>rider-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The exception:

```
<12/06/2019 3:50:24 PM AEST> <Error> <Munger> <BEA-2156200> <Unable to load 
descriptor weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@6e4b9e8e finder:
weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@764267fe annotation: /WEB-
INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml of
module com.coles.merch-PromoAPI-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.war. The error is 
weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: Unmarshaller failed
```

Was looking at a number of answers on so:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083997/not-able-to-deploy-a-simple-spring-boot-application-on-weblogic-12c) but this did not solve the issue at my end.

This is a very basic vanilla spring rest service that I am trying to deploy.
So not sure why am encountering this error and also wondering why I need tomcat jars since I am not needing to use embedded server that spring boot ships with .

Comment: finally figured it out - it seems code compiled in Java 1.8 does not play well with weblogic 12.1.3.The same code if compiled in 1.7 is getting deployed successfully.  I upgraded my weblogic to 12.2.1.3 and 1.8 compiled code runs fine

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would try to disable Tomcat at Spring Boot application level.

Comment: how do I do that ? I have the 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat' scope as provided